# Irreducible surface singularity that is not a local set-theoretical complete intersection

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, several-complex-variables

I have been looking for a criterion for the germ of an irreducible complex surface singularity $(X,x)$ to be a set-theoretical complete intersection.

A germ $(X,x)$ of an isolated complex singularity of dimension $k$ is said to be an isolated complete intersection singularity if for some embedding $(X,x) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}^{k+s}$, the ideal of functions that vanish on $(X,x)$ can be generated by $f_1, \ldots, f_s$ holomorphic functions of in $\mathbb{C}^{k+s}$.

A germ $(X,x)$ of an isolated complex singularity of dimension $k$ is said to be a set theoretical isolated complete intersection if the analytic set defined by the embedding of $X$ in some euclidean complex space can be written as the zeros of as many holomorphic functions as the codimension of the space in that euclidean space.

I have noticed that often the difference between "complete intersection" and "set-theoretical complete intersection" is blurred in the literature. And a lot of papers on the topic, do not define the object (as it is assumed to be widely known in the area) or they define it *casually*.

Sometimes it is said that a a singularity $(X,x)$ of pure dimension $r$ is a complete intersection if it can be expressed as the zeroes of $n-r$ polynomials in $\mathbb{C}^n$. But this is the weaker notion of set-theoretical complete intersection.

In https://www.liverpool.ac.uk/~ctcw/normsurf.pdf, C.T.C. Wall shows an example of a surface singularity which is not a complete intersection (end of page 2 and page 3). The singularity is the one generated by the polynomials $$f_1 = xz-y^2, f_2 = xw-yz, f_3 = yw-z^2$$ in  $\mathbb{C}^4$.

(In a previous version of this question I erroneously claimed that $V(f_1) \cap V(f_2)$ was contained in $V(f_3)$ (and that it was easy to see!) and the writing suggested somehow that C.T.C Wall was not being clear about the definitions. So my apologies). @inkspot pointed out the error in the comments. However, it is not clear to me how to show that $X$ is not a set-theoretical complete intersection.

> My question is, what are examples of irreducible complex surface singularities that are not set-theoretical complete intersections? And if it is studied somewhere the criterion for (the germ of) an irreducible analytic space to be a (local) set-theoretical complete intersection?

I have found tons of examples of varieties that are local complete intersection but not global complete intersections. And of set-theoretical (local and global) complete intersections that are not complete intersections in the *ideal* sense of the number of generators of their defining ideals. But not much in the necessary conditions for an algebraic set to be a set-theoretical intersection near a given point.

Comment: When you write "irreducible complex surface singularities", do you actually mean "unibranch complex surface singularities"?  It is quite straightforward to write down irreducible surfaces that have an isolated surface singularity that is not a set-theoretical complete intersection.  It is considerably harder to find one that is unibranch.

Comment: By “irreducible complex surface singularity” I mean irreducible as complex analytic germ for example equivalent to saying that its normalization has only one component). Reduced does not play a role here, since once that you have an irreducible germ, you may take the radical of its defining ideal which defines the same space (set theoretically) and it is reduced. I have never heard the word “unibranch” unless speaking about plane curves.

Comment: I am thinking about the germ. So for example a nodal curve is irreducible but its germ at the double point is not.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "germ".

Comment: A complex analytic space $(X, O_X)$ is a space which locally looks like the common zeros of analytic functions defined on some open set of complex Euclidean space. A singularity is the localization of $O_X$ at a point $x \in X$. Which gives in a standard way (up to choosing some generators of the maximal ideal), an analytic embedding of a neighborhood of $x$ (in $X$) into some Euclidean complex space.

Comment: The germ is the data $X,x, O_{X,x}$.

Comment: @JasonStarr I have checked the definiton of unibranch local ring and $O_{X,x}$ is unibranch if and only if only one local  analytic irreducible component of $X$ passes through $x$. So definitions match up in the local setting I am interested.

Comment: @Paul: I don't follow your calculation. In the example you give, $X$ is the cone over a twisted cubic $\gamma$ in $\mathbb P^3$. The equations $f_1=f_2=0$ define $\gamma\cup\ell$ where $\ell$ is a line either tangent or secant to $\gamma$. So in $\mathbb C^4$ the intersection $V(f_1)\cap V(f_2)$ is the union of $X$ and a plane.

Comment: @inkspot You are absolutely right. I divided by  $0$ at some point. My bad. I will edit the question to leave just the original question. (note that this does not show that $X$ is not a set theoretical  complete intersection but rather than one  cannot extract a set theoretical complete intersection from these equations.)

Comment: This might be an open problem, similar to the problem that all curves in projective space are set-theoretic complete intersections. The only obstruction I know in the local case is local cohomology, but it vanishes in this case.

Comment: @HailongDao Yes, after two days looking for references. I only found one example in an old paper "Certain cones are not set-theoretic complete intersections" by Simha (1974). This example is a complex dimension $4$ irreducible isolated singularity in $\mathbb{C}^6 $. This made my  realize that the question which might seem innocent at first sight, might also be non trivial.

Comment: Yes, for high dimension we can give examples due to the cohomological obstruction mentioned above. But it is much harder for curves and surfaces.