# Equations needed to define a normal complex surface singularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, singularity-theory, several-complex-variables

This questions is highly related with this other question of mine: [Irreducible surface singularity that is not a local set-theoretical complete intersection](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315588/irreducible-surface-singularity-that-is-not-a-local-set-theoretical-complete-int) I just thought that a different look at the same problem wouldn't hurt. I hope this does not bother anyone.

Let $(X,x)$ be the germ of a normal complex surface singularity. And suppose that it has embedding dimension equal to $n$. That is, if $m$ is the maximal ideal of the local ring $O_{X,x}$ the dimension of $m/m^2$ as a module over $O_{X,x}/m$ is $n$.

How many equations are needed in general to define $X$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$? Obviously in terms of $n$. The question has two variants,

First, how many equations in $\mathbb{C}\{z_1, \ldots, z_n\}$ are needed to generate the defining ideal of $(X,x)$?

Secomd, how many equations are needed to define $(X,x)$ set-theoretically? That is, what is the minimal $k$ such that there exists an ideal $I$ with $X=V(I)$ set theoretically and $I$ can be generated by $k$ equations.

Is it possible that there exists a normal complex surface singularity for which it is needed more than $n-1$ equations in any of the two senses above?

Comment: The number of equations could be unbounded (Moh). Set-theoretically, the record is $n$, by Eisenbud-Evans (their proof should adapt to the local case). For integral curves or surfaces, as I commented on your previous post, it looks hopeless at the moment.

Comment: So, in the first question (for surfaces) the number of equations is unbounded?  Are there examples realizing any $k>n$?

Comment: Yes: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1979-077-03/S0002-9939-1979-0545586-0/S0002-9939-1979-0545586-0.pdf